# Inverse Function Theorem for Manifolds with Boundary as the Domain

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, inverse-function-theorem

In Lee's Smooth Manifolds, it is written that the inverse function theorem can fail for manifolds with boundary. As hint, it is given the inclusion of half space into euclidean space $\iota:\mathbb{H}^n\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$
 My guess is that this is merely a matter of being open rather than really deep problems, or?

Comment: I think the answers at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/67640/inverse-function-theorem-on-manifolds-with-boundary would give you your desired answer.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand the consequence. Clearly a map with half space as domain is smooth iff locally there exists extension to an open subset of euclidean space overlapping with half space. Its derivative then is as usual and so the local inverse function theorem applies. Restricting back to half space we obtain a smooth local bijection with smooth inverse???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, your guess is right -- it's just that you can't find (open) neighborhoods of the given points that are diffeomorphic.

The theorem you're looking at in my book (Thm. 4.5) says

> *Suppose $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds, and $F:M\to N$ is a smooth
>   map. If $p\in M$ is a point such that $dF_p$ is invertible, then there
>   are connected neighborhoods $U_0$ of $p$ and $V_0$ of $F(p)$ such that
>   $F|_{U_0}: U_0\to V_0$ is a diffeomorphism.*

What fails in an example like $\iota:\mathbb H^n\to \mathbb R^n$ is that you can't find any neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb H^n$ that's diffeomorphic to a neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb R^n$.

It boils down to what we mean by the word "locally." To say a map $F:M\to N$ is locally invertible usually means (at least) that for each $p\in M$, there exist a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ and a neighborhood $V$ of $f(p)$ such that $f|_U:U\to V$ is bijective. If you don't require $V$ to be a neighborhood, then every smooth immersion would be locally invertible. I guess you could define the term that way, but it's not the way most people understand it.

Comment: Oooohhh, I'm huge fan of you!!!!!!! =DD Just reading SM right now after TM =D - may I ask u why there is no continuous extension of the identity on the circle to the plane ($\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{S},\mathrm{E}}:\mathrm{R}^2\to\mathbb{S}$) ...I mean intuitively this seems right

Comment: But what about $\hat{\tau}_\mathrm{E}:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n:x\mapsto x$? It shows that the inclusion as map between manifolds is smooth by definition (except the fact that it is not continuous). Surely continuity is really important for smoothness between manifolds (since otherwise the step function would be smooth) but apart from that (*open* sets) I don't see what really bad is happening on the given example - it seems perfectly smooth according to what we think of smoothness - so my question here...

Comment: @Freeze_S: Not quite sure what you're asking.  But the problem with the map $\iota:\mathbb H^n\to \mathbb R^n$ is not about smoothness -- it's perfectly smooth; it's just not a local diffeomorphism.

Comment: About the identity $\mathbb S^1\to \mathbb S^1$: this has no continuous extension to the whole plane, or even to the closed disk (as a map into $\mathbb S^1$), but this is not so easy to prove. The proof relies on properties of the fundamental group (see my Introduction to Topological Manifolds, Chapters 7 & 8).

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the compliment!

Comment: But isn't it locally invertible with smooth local inverse. What I mean is that this example is more about domains and continuity rather than really smoothness. So my question is: Is there examples which show that smoothness really seems to fail for local inverse at boundary (sth like the step function for smoothness definition)?

Comment: It boils down to what we mean by the word "locally."  To say a map $F:M\to N$ is locally invertible usually means (at leasst) that for each $p\in M$, there exist a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ and a _neighborhood_ $V$ of $f(p)$ such that $f|_U:U\to V$ is bijective.  If you don't require $V$ to be open, then every smooth immersion would be locally invertible. I guess you could define the term that way, but it's not the way most people understand it.

Comment: Ah right, that was Kind of the example i was looking for. Would u mind posting this as answer so I can close this thread?

Comment: Btw I guess by intuition that requiring the neighborhoods to be open (hausdorff's definition of neighborhood should suffice) can be omitted ...moreover is there an example violating connectedness - I mean if someone found by accident while the IFT not necessarily applies that a function is a local diffeomorphism but with disconnected nbhds then is it always possible to restrict nbhds to connected ones and still maintain bijectivity? Surely continuity will still remain in that case as well as smoothness...

Comment: OK, I've added my comment about local immersions to the answer.