# Extension of Inverse Function Theorem to Manifold with Boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, inverse-function-theorem

Recently i learned that we can't extend inverse function theorem in Euclidean space to manifold with boundary as domain. More precisely, if we have a smooth map $F : M \to N$ where $M$ is a manifold with boundary and $N$ is a manifold without boundary, for any $p \in M$ such that $dF_p$ invertible we can't always has a diffeomorphism  $F|_{U_0} : U_0 \to V_0$ on the smaller nbhds $U_0$ of $p$ and $V_0$ of $F(p)$.

The example for such map is the inclusion map $\iota : \mathbb{H}^n \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723497/inverse-function-theorem-for-manifolds-with-boundary-as-the-domain) or [Lee's smooth manifold](https://books.google.co.id/books?redir_esc=y&hl=id&id=eqfgZtjQceYC&q=inverse+function+theorem#v=snippet&q=inverse%20function%20theorem&f=false). I'm trying to prove for the general case but i'm fail. So i guess that there are map (with some manifold $M$ as domain) that we can extend IFT ? The problem is that i can't find an example for such map.

Is there any class of map (or class of manifold with boundary) such that we can extend IFT ?

Any help or hints will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the general case".  As soon as you have one counterexample, you know the result is false.